# How to create a mean of a variable as a new variable in SPSS?

Tags: mean, spss

I would like to create a mean of a variable as a new variable. For example, my data consists of individual responses across several surveys. I would like to calculate a mean of all the responses for each survey and create a new variable that would reflect that.

What might be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Actually, the method I used includes missing values. Is there a way to exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

```
Aggregate
/BREAK survey
/SurveyMean=mean(variable X).
```

Comment: Thanks Deep North. I have defined the missing values but I am still not getting the same results as when I do it manually. I think it has to do with the mean() option. When I compute a variable from few variables the same thing happens if I use mean() option instead of (var1+var2+var3)/3. But in the aggregate command I can't use (var1+var2+var3)/3 because I have way too many cases and they are different from one survey to the next. So I can't think of any other way than using a mean. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's right: the + operator handles missing values differently from `MEAN`. For some details, see [this tutorial](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-sum-cautionary-note/).